# Using "normal" Ubuntu on convertible with multitouch and so on

Tags: laptop, 16.04, multi-touch, tablet, display-rotation

I'd like to run Ubuntu 16.04 (not Ubuntu Touch) on an Intel tablet or a convertible laptop. Are there drivers for support of multi-touch gestures, onscreen keyboard, GPS, rotation sensor etc. as used in Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what device you're looking to get, hardware support will differ. I can tell you that my Acer Aspire laptop with a touchscreen works perfectly on Ubuntu and its derivatives. You could always boot from a live cd/usb to see how it works on your laptop.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen